# doesn't increment php after first try

Tags: php, upload, increment

I tried the below incrementer and it works on first go, but then it doesn't.

For example:

1) Upload file: "picture.png"  -----> stores picture.png | OK

2) Upload File: "picture.png"  -----> changes picture.png to 1picture.png | OK

3) Upload File: "picture.png"  -----> Doesn't work, directory only have the 2 pictures above.

```
if(file_exists($path . $picName)) {
   $incrementer = 1;
   $path =  $path . $incrementer++;  
   move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $picName);
}
```

How come it doesn't increment no more?

Comment: You're resetting the counter to 1 each time it goes in the loop.

Comment: You probably need a while loop in there. At the moment, if the initial picture is there, it'll always use `1picture.png` - there's nothing there to carry on trying to see if `2picture.png` might be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep resetting your `$incrementer` on each loop iteration. You need to set it outside of your loop:

```
$incrementer = 1;
// start loop
  if(file_exists($path . $picName)) {
     $path =  $path . $incrementer++;  
     move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $picName);
  }
// end loop
```

If the files are being uploaded one at a time then this won't work at all as your PHP script, including all of the variables you set in it end with each execution of that script. In that case you would need to save that value in a database, session, or some other (semi-)persistent storage so it would be available across script executions.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION[incrementer']) 
    $_SESSION[incrementer'] = 1;
}
if(file_exists($path . $picName)) {
    $path =  $path . $_SESSION['incrementer']++;  
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $picName);
}
```

Comment: I've moved the incrementer outside the if statement now, but still doesn't work. I see a guide like this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-file-exists-append-number-to-name/ and it seems to work fine for them. Don't think they created a database value for it.

Comment: You're doing something a bit different for them. Based on your comment to the other answer the second part of my answer applies.

Comment: I think I may use session. Would this work? $incrementer = $_SESSION['counter']=1;

Comment: Thanks it works. What happens if another user from another computer tries the same thing, but uses the same name. How will the session behave?

Comment: This works only because you are testing unly one user using the same browser. On another browser/user $_SESSION will be empty

Comment: Makes sense. I'll overhaul my code after I've finish my constraints for image types. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if file already exist already then change the file-name. To make filne-name unique I mostly append CurrentTime before the file-name. You can use the Random-Number also.

```
$picName = time().$picName;
while(file_exists($path . $picName))
{
   $picName = time().$picName;
}

move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $picName);
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I may append time ontop of the increment number. Just incase other users upload same time and same file name. Unlikely but might as well heh

Comment: yes you can do that and also you can append random-number. 
$picName = time().rand(1, 9999).$picName;

Answer (score 0):

you need a while loop:

```
$incrementer = 1;
$basepath='path/';
$path =  $basepath; 

while(file_exists($path . $picName)) {
   $path =  $basepath . ($incrementer++);  
}

move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $picName);
```

Comment: I tried this but it just keeps on loading when I submit the form.